# Google Pixel C erratic USB data connection

Tags: usb

Any ideas why some days my computers "see" my Pixel C over USB, some days they don't?  Two different computers, two different cables, also an older USB cable with USB-C adapter.  All work well for charging.  But often I don't get the menu that lets me choose a data connection, the tablet isn't detected at all.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the computer's fault, not the phone.

Comment: Two different computers though.  Both of which recognize several similar devices - phones, other tablets - over USB just fine.

Comment: Hm. What file protocol is it set to when it connects? (MTP or PTP)

Comment: The point is - it DOESN'T connect!  We don't get as far as the pull-down menu to choose transfer protocol.